# How to use multiple repository with unit of work?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

In the code below I want to get data using Repository or from multiple repositories in a controller.

I have two question:

How not to use an empty constructor?
 and when used the uncommented code returns a null exception?

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    private IStudentRepository _studentRepository;
    public StudentController() { }
    public StudentController(IStudentRepository studentRepository)
    {
        _studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }        
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var x = _studentRepository.GetAll().ToList();
        return View();


        //using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new PollingSystemDbContext()))
        //{
        //    var x = unitOfWork.IStudentRepository.GetAll();
        //    var list = x.ToList();
        //    return View();
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: The Commented code works fine.

Answer (score 2):

• By default Controllers require a parameter-less constructor to function. If you don't want to keep the unused parameter-less constructor in the Controller, you can either:

1. Override the DefaultControllerFactory and wire it so it returns a new instance of a Controller with your dependencies.

   ```
   public class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory {
       protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) {
           if (controllerType == typeof(StudentController)) {
               return new StudentController(new StudentRepository());
           }
           return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
       }
   }
   ```

Then register the new factory in `global.asax`

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new CustomControllerFactory());
```

Keep in mind, that for each controller, you'll need to wire the dependencies yourself.

2. A better approach is to look into using an `IoC Container` such as `StructureMap` to wire up the dependencies for you.

Simply install the following package `StructureMap.MVC5.Update`.

If your dependencies follow the default convention of `IDependency` for interfaces, and `Dependency` for implementations, they will be automatically picked up and wired by `StructureMap`.

If you need to wire a specific dependency, navigate to `DefaultRegistry.cs` and add your dependencies.

• The commented code returns null reference exception because you're not passing the model back to the view

```
var list = x.ToList();
return View(list); //pass the list back
```

Comment: Excellent job on your first answer! However, I would suggest you take a look at the markdown editing guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to make your answers even better in the future. Fantastic job!